# How do I use .NET on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, webserver

I have been running a webserver on my Ubuntu server. Now my friend wants me to also run .NET on my server.

How do I run .NET on it? I know nothing about .NET, though my friend is quite good at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be what you are looking for:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mod-mono-server

Mono is the .net framework for Linux

Comment: @kritya you actually will need to install the package for the mono module for apache2 or whatever other web server you use.  Then, your friend will be able to use .net coded pages off of your web server.